# Cannot install phonegap on MAC OS

Tags: node.js, macos, terminal, npm

I have tried to install phonegap with the following command.

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/npm install -g phonegap@latest
```

However I get this output. I cannot find any log, where is it? Or any help with the issue.

```
> ws@0.4.31 install     /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/connect-phonegap/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


> ws@0.4.31 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/connect-phonegap/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws
 > (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

 /usr/local/bin/phonegap -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/bin/phonegap.js

 phonegap@5.3.9 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap
 ├── pluralize@0.0.4
 ├── colors@0.6.0-1
 ├── semver@1.1.0
 ├── minimist@0.1.0
 ├── qrcode-terminal@0.9.4
 ├── shelljs@0.1.4 
 ├── prompt@0.2.11 (revalidator@0.1.8, pkginfo@0.3.1, read@1.0.7, winston@0.6.2, utile@0.2.1)
 ├── phonegap-build@0.9.2 (colors@0.6.2, qrcode-terminal@0.8.0, optimist@0.3.7, shelljs@0.0.9, phonegap-build-api@0.3.3)
 ├── connect-phonegap@0.18.1 (home-dir@0.1.2, connect-inject@0.3.2, ip@0.3.1, adm-zip@0.4.7, request-progress@0.3.1, http-proxy@1.8.1, walkdir@0.0.8, shelljs@0.2.6, useragent@2.0.8, request@2.33.0, node-static@0.7.0, gaze@0.4.3, tar@0.1.19, localtunnel@1.3.0, socket.io@1.0.4, archiver@0.14.3, connect@2.12.0)
 └── cordova@5.4.1 (underscore@1.7.0, q@1.0.1, ansi@0.3.0, nopt@3.0.1, update-notifier@0.5.0, cordova-lib@5.4.1)
```

I am using node.js build 4.2.3 and using Mac OS

After i run the above command , I ran the command phonegap to ensure the install worked but i get the  below output. Any ideas?

```
phonegap
-bash: phonegap: command not found
```

Comment: That command does not install npm, it uses npm to install phonegap from npm. Also, that output does not look like it failed.

Comment: when i type the command phone gap it does not work. I will edit the post to be clear.

Comment: Post now has been updated with clearer information. Thanks

Comment: Is `/usr/local/bin` in your PATH? Try using `/usr/local/bin/phonegap`.

Comment: I tried this as to your feedback  sudo /usr/local/bin/phonegap/npm install -g phonegap@latest 
and got this response
sudo: /usr/local/bin/phonegap/npm: command not found

Comment: I mean just `/usr/local/bin/phonegap`, not `/usr/local/bin/phonegap/npm`. Your terminal output says the `phonegap` script was linked to `/usr/local/bin/phonegap`.

Comment: I am sorry I do not understand i tried both /usr/local/bin/phonegap install -g phonegap@latest  and /usr/local/bin/phonegap and both replied with env: node: No such file or directory

Comment: answered and fixed below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FIXED the issue. Like stated in feedback the from Alexander O'Mara the installation was successful. My issue was phone gap was not firing.

The reason for this is the paths were not in etc/paths. so I did the following

In terminal (mac) ran this command
      sudo vi /etc/paths

The file contented the following
     /usr/bin
     /bin
     /usr/sbin
     /sbin
     /usr/local/mysql/bin

I added the below paths (press "i" to insert if you are new to terminal)
     /usr/local/bin
     /usr/local/sbin

The file now looked like this
     /usr/local/bin
     /usr/local/sbin
     /usr/bin
     /bin
     /usr/sbin
     /sbin
     /usr/local/mysql/bin

Close the file (esc key then type "ZZ")

Then restart terminal. All will work fine ... or id did form me.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out to [install PhoneGap on Mac](http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started/1-install-phonegap/desktop/#mac)

And if you want to install node module globally, don't use `sudo`.

Comment: I followed http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started/1-install-phonegap/cli/ which is the command line interface as I understand that has better features and allows you to edit the config.xml files

Comment: without sudo i get errors like the following Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap'

Comment: answered and fixed below